# How can I get all new objects name created from a function constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am working on a javaScript project, building a turned based game, and I have created a function constructor for the Players.

I added a css class for each player, with the same name of the players.

Below I added my js code:

```
function Player(name, image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
}

var player1 = new Player("kakashi", "ninja.png");
var player2 = new Player("mightyGuy", "samurai.png");

function checkClass() {
        $.each(classList, function(index, cssClass) {
            if (
                cssClass === "wall" ||
                cssClass === "kakashi" ||
                cssClass === "mightyGuy"
            ) {
                blocked = true;
            }
        });
    }
```

How could I get all new player.name created from this constructor in order to check if a specific divCell has any player.name class??

So instead of write cssClass === "kakashi" || cssClass === "mightyGuy"

I would simply write it one time, and automatically it will check all css classes by Player.name.

Update question: 
This is the way I end up using in my code:

```
function Player(name, image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
}

var player1 = new Player("kakashi", "ninja.png");
var player2 = new Player("mightyGuy", "samurai.png");

function checkClass() {
    $.each(classList, function(index, cssClass) {
        if (
            cssClass === "wall" ||
            cssClass == passivePlayer.name
        ) {
            blocked = true;
        }
    });
}
```

I used this way because I don't need to write any player name by using the var passivePlayer (that could be any player except the activePlayer)

Answer (score 0):

you can add the classes to an object and check if they exist.

```
function Player(name, image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
}

var player1 = new Player("kakashi", "ninja.png");
var player2 = new Player("mightyGuy", "samurai.png");
function checkClass() {
    const checkList = {
        wall: true,
        kakashi: true,
        mightyGuy: true
    }

    $.each(classList, function (index, cssClass) {
        if (checkList[cssClass]) {
            blocked = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and help!! 
I tried it and it works perfectly. However I end up using another way because I could avoid write the players name:

   function checkClass() {
        $.each(classList, function(index, cssClass) {
            if (
                cssClass === "wall" ||
                cssClass == passivePlayer.name
            ) {
                blocked = true;
            }
        });
    }

Comment: I apologise to write code in this way, in a comment, but it doesn't let me format the code correctly for answering a comment.

Comment: can you update your original question to incorporate the changes you made?

Comment: Yes sure! I just updated it! I am still open to more advice and feedback :)
Thank you so much for your answer!